# Why does Experimental Modal Analysis need a reference signal?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, signal-processing, modal-analysis

I need to conduct a vibration experiment with 3 accelerometers for a gear box. I'm reading the theory of mainly how to perform the vibration analysis but I don't understand why EMA needs a reference signal, and what it means by it? Also, is it the same for operational modal analysis?

Comment: Keep reading till you find out how a reference signal is *used*. Then you will know if you need it, and why. You don't *always* need a reference signal - it depends what you are trying to measure.

Comment: @alephzero I have, thanks. When we derive the vibration mode shapes thriugh numerical simulations based on the mathematical model, is that considered numerical modal analysis? and then we can correlate with experimental modal analysis?